# Why new products are visible smaller as compared to recently products on homepage. Today it looks fine but how come

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, product-images, new-products, home-page

I am building an eCommerce website named [www.bookslab.in](http://www.bookslab.in). On my homepage when i added the 2 widgets "New Products" & "Recently Viewed" products then new products section is visible smaller as compared to recently viewed products. I don't know why this is happening. I had cleaned the Index & Magento cache still they are same. I am attaching the screenshot of my website homepage. Can anybody explain me how automatically it looks great now?

[image]

Comment: Hey if you getting product form widget then , this is common issue , For solution you have to write a code for css. then  you will get same size as you like

Comment: I know i had tried that also but did not worked for me

Comment: Recently Viewed product is not show at this time can you please add this so we can check it?

Comment: To see recently viewed products you have to log in my website

Comment: I don't know how it is looking perfect today, when i checked my website. Is someone changed. Can someone explain me what has hapen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your new products name is smaller than the older one. You need to assign products name in equal lengths or give the specific `minimum-height` to the name class in your css. This may be helps you.

Comment: Okzz i will check n get back to u

Comment: it does not work. Can you suggest me the css code or provide me the new solution

Comment: I don't have the code right now, but i did it in one of my project, you van find the name class by right click on the product name.

Comment: Okzz i will check

Comment: Not worked for me. I added the min-height, but still does not worked.I think the problem is  with the images of recent books, if we decrease these then it will look similar with the above products. If you think this is right, so do you know how to do this.